# Php Autocompletion: Tell IDE which class is inherited

Tags: php, autocomplete, prestashop, phped

I'm running into some autocompletion problems when using PHPed to develop a PrestaShop module.

When declaring a class like this for example

```
class myModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
```

The IDE won't recognize the parent class `ModuleFrontController` because it's originally declared as `class ModuleFrontControllerCore{..}` and PS somehow does an `eval` to remove `Core` at the end.

So how can I tell the IDE to look inside `ModuleFrontControllerCore`?
I tried

```
/*
* @uses ModuleFrontControllerCore
*/
class myModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController{

    /**
    * this one worked for $module property
    * @var ModuleCore
    */
    public $module;
}
```

I also used `@var ModuleFrontControllerCore` which, as expected, didn't work.
Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I found this solution for now.I can add any class I need.
https://gist.github.com/xbb/1210966 (copy to PS root)

Comment: I don't understand how it could work. I'm using netbeans. Any hints? Can you explain any better?

Comment: You need to provide declarations of all used classes in a separate file and put the file on your project root (you also need to open it for once so the IDE reads it).

Comment: What you mean by "open it for once" ?

Comment: I mean open it at least once so that the IDE would take it into consideration